# android:imeOptions="actionNext" not working

Tags: android, android-layout, textinput, imeoptions

I am creating signup page but and adding next button to every TextInputEditText and it is working perfectly without any issue,

but whenever I add `android:digits="0123456789qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm_ "` in layout then it doesn't work.

What will be the probable reason for the solution for it??

below is my code snippet.

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColorHint="#c0c0c0"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:theme="@style/MyTextInputLayoutStyle">
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/activity_register_edit_text_state"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="@string/state_region"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                       android:digits="0123456789qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm_ "            
           android:inputType="textPersonName"
                         android:padding="@dimen/edittext_padding"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color_light"
                        android:theme="@style/MyTextInputLayoutStyle"
                        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextErrorAppearance"
                        app:xfont="@string/roboto_regular" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You also  need to add `android:inputType="text"` in your `TextInputEditText`

Comment: I tried with already, even in question also i have added android:inputType

Comment: Test case just change `app:theme="@style/MyTextInputLayoutStyle"`  with `style="@style/MyTextInputLayoutStyle"`

Comment: tried, not luck

Comment: Try adding android:maxLines="1" along with android:inputType="text"

Comment: Tried already, no luck, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you set android:digits in EditText orTextInputEditText, it allows only digit or character which you have defined in it. In android soft input (Key Board) there is the next button have a unique code that is not defined in android: digits.

refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions) for better understanding